# Using perl command line arguments in the format of both while(<>) ARGV[1], possibly using a shift command?

Tags: perl, arguments

I basically want to the do something like

```
while(<>){
     my ($one, $two, $three) = split;
     if ($one > ARGV[1]){
          #some commands
     }
}
```

Where I would invoke it like

```
./script.pl text.txt 50
```

But obviously I don't want the while loop to read anything from 50
Any ideas on the best cleanest way to do this, like if I could shift the command line arguments somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way this is done, is to assign @ARGV to a list of variables so the script documents what you were expecting to be passed

```
my ($file, $count) = @ARGV ;
```

Of course, this doesn't actually check the validity of what - if anything - is actually passed.  If you want that, there are many options processing modules to choose from. Many like [Getopt::Long](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long) but I prefer [Getopt::Lucid.](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Lucid)  YMMV.

As with most things perl, Gabor Szabo has a great page about @ARGV [here](http://perlmaven.com/argv-in-perl).  You may find this quote from it useful:

> ### How to extract the command line arguments from `@ARGV`
>
> `@ARGV` is just a regular array in Perl. The only difference from arrays that you create, is that it does not need to be declared and it is populated by Perl when your script starts.
>
> Aside from these issue, you can handle it as a regular array. You can go over the elements using `foreach`, or access them one by one using an index: `$ARGV[0]`.
>
> You can also use shift, unshift, pop or push on this array.
>
> Indeed, not only can you fetch the content of `@ARGV`, you can also change it.
>
> If you expect a single value on the command line you can check what was it, or if it was provided at all by looking at `$ARGV[0]`. If you expect two variables you will also check `$ARGV[1]`.

Answer (score 4):

`<>` reads from the [`ARGV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlvar#ARGV2) filehandle, which you can think of as a concatenation of all the filenames in [`@ARGV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlvar#ARGV1). The `ARGV` filehandle won't be initialized until `<>` is called, so it is safe to manipulate `@ARGV` before your while loop.

```
my $val = pop @ARGV;             # take last argument
my ($val) = splice @ARGV, 1, 1;  # take 2nd argument
...
while (<>) {      # now ARGV fh uses whatever is currently in @ARGV
    my ($one,$two,$three) = split;
    if ($one > $val) { ... }
}
```

Also note that if `@ARGV` is empty, the `<>` operator will read from standard input. So long as you empty the `@ARGV` array before you try to read from `<>`, something like this will also work with `<>`:

```
./script.pl 50 < text.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you rearrange the order of the arguments

```
./script.pl 50 text.txt
```

Putting the file name(s) last is a more common practice, and it simplifies the needed code to the following:

```
my $limit = shift(@ARGV);

while (<>) {
    my @fields = split;
    if ($fields[0] > $limit) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The trick is to remove all but the file names from `@ARGV` before `while (<>)`.

This practice has the additional advantage that the following will simply read from STDIN:

```
./script.pl 50
```